# When the backend parses the file, the frontend reports an error and access timeout

Tags: java

I am uploading a file and parsing the file data in the background and saving it to the database, If the background parsing time is too long, the page will report an error connection timeout, and the backend will print `java.io.IOException: Broken pipe` on the console, But the data will continue to be written, I know that the timeout can be adjusted to avoid this problem, I have adjusted it to 20s, but the backend write time may be longer, I can't add the timeout time again

Comment: I search some doc and see websocket, but I do not know hwo to change my code...

Comment: You might need to do Async calls instead.   Your code working synchronously does not seem to work, and simply increasing the timeout is not a viable solution.  Showing your code might allow others to understand how to help you better.

Comment: Could you please explain your use case, it is not clear  enough to provide an answer/direction. Please post any code (sample) that you might have, it shall be helpful.